# overwrite member data with member function c++

Tags: c++, class, member

I'm having some trouble putting together some code, and my problem boils down to this:

I have a class with several data members, which I use a constructor to set.

I later want to change some of those data members, if a certain public member function is called.

for example:

```
class example
{
     public:
                  int Test
                  void changeTest ( int newTest) { Test = newTest;}
}
```

I'm getting the unqualified id error regarding Test inside the changeTest() function.

Is what I'm trying to do not possible or am I just doing it wrong? I can't seem to find a good resource on the internet.

Comment: You are missing semicolons

Comment: First  please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need an MCVE and the complete and unedited error, in full, to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
class example
{
     public:
         int Test //<-- Missing semicolon here, should be int Test;
         void changeTest ( int newTest) { Test = newTest;}
} //<-- Missing semicolon here too.
```

You are missing a semicolon, so you get an unqualified identifier error, and the unqualified identifier is `Test`. Most old compilers give weird errors, but many modern ones say:

> Error: expected a ';'

In addition, the end of your class also needs a semicolon, which I have mentioned above.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg edited